# matplotlib installation is failing on Ubuntu 17.04 32 bit os

Tags: python, matplotlib, png, freetype, ubuntu-17.04

pip install matplotlib is throwing error :

```
============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png
                        * Try installing freetype with `apt-get install
                        * libfreetype6-dev` and pkg-config with `apt-get
                        * install pkg-config`
                        * Try installing png with `apt-get install
                        * libpng12-dev` and pkg-config with `apt-get install
                        * pkg-config`

----------------------------------------
```

and installations of both libfreetype6-dev and libpng12-dev is failing because of "Unable to Locate Package" error

```
============================================================================
```

E: Unable to locate package libfreetype6-dev
E: Unable to locate package libpng12-dev

I tried all the options mentioned in other posts on stackoverflow.

I also tried installing libfreetype6-dev, libpng12-dev using binary files, but no luck. It threw architecture incompatibility error.

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 , 32 bit OS i386 architecture on VMWare.

Comment: why not 64bit??

Comment: Have been using it for long time now. I guess VMWare free desktop version doesnt support 64-Bit Ubuntu OS.